# how to exclude some letters with regex

Tags: regex

I have a string:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.littlebigplay.games.premium.plurals&click=541255b82bc957475c7b6222d1a980a5&mysuffix={HELLO_WORLD}&optid=541255b82bc957475c7b`

I need `541255b82bc957475c7b6222d1a980a5` - (I want to extract click)/ I use next regex `click=(.+?)&` but it take `&click=541255b82bc957475c7b6222d1a980a5&`.

How I can extract without "click=" and "&"?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the flavour of regex you use, some of them support lookbehind structures, that would be the easiest:

`(?<=click=)([^&]+)`

You can test is here: https://regex101.com/r/61LFnt/1/